# SqlDataAdapter optimize foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

This C# code is tested as working, but looks inefficient to me.  How can I avoid all of the overhead in each `foreach` interation for say a 1,000 rows?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);  // strConn is set elsewhere in the code
string strSQL = "select pkCustomer from Customer where YearEndDeactivateInd = 1";
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
adap.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string strSQL1 = "update Ticket set activeInd = 0 where fkCustomer = " + row["pkCustomer"].ToString();
    SqlDataAdapter adap1 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL1, con);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    adap1.Fill(dt1);
}

con.Close();
```

I am updating one table based on the results of another.  Should I pursue using batch update instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use query like this

```
update Ticket
set activeInd = 0
where fkCustomer in (
    select pkCustomer
    from Customer
    where YearEndDeactivateInd = 1
)
```

Do it without adapter

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
    string sql = "here query above";
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do it all in one query.

e.g.

```
UPDATE Ticket 
  SET activeInd = 0 
WHERE 
  fkCustomer IN 
    (SELECT pkCustomer 
     FROM Customer 
     WHERE YearEndDeactivateInd = 1
    )
```

Or maybe better:

```
UPDATE T 
  SET activeInd = 0 
FROM 
  Ticket T 
  INNER JOIN Customer C 
    ON T.fkCustomer = C.pkCustomer 
WHERE 
  C.YearEndDeactivateInd = 1
```

Either way, SQL will be far more efficient at this by itself.